# Meaning of the statement "$a\in I$ is a general element of $I$"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Suppose $I$ is an ideal in a Noetherian local ring $(R,m)$. In some papers I have seen the following statement:

*"$a\in I$ is a general element of $I$"*.

**What is the definition of general element in an ideal?**

Sometimes it is referred as *superficial element* or *filter regular element*.

Reference: See Lemma 2.3 of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404910000411).

Comment: It would be hard to answer without further context?

Comment: I think a general element of an ideal is usually a general linear combination of some fixed (finite) set of generators for the ideal.

In Lemma 2.3 of the paper you linked, $G$ is a graded ring and $f$ is a general element in $G_1$. Here, $G_1$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $G_0$, so the meaning of 'general' is clear. Perhaps you meant to ask about Lemma 3.2, which does have a general element of an ideal.

Comment: @ZachTeitler if we start with a general element, how to see that it can be a filter regular element (as mentioned in the proof of Lemma 2.3)?

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304040.pdf?fname=cm&font=TypeI ?

Comment: @user1 Could you please briefly explain what is written in the reference  you have given. I looked into the reference but the prerequisite seems to be a bit too much for me.

Comment: In the linked paper, they seem to be using the phrase "general element" to simply mean "arbitrary element" unless I'm misreading.

Comment: @Cusp Let $V \subset G$ be a finite dimensional vector space. If every element of $V$ lies in one of the associated primes of $L$, then the ideal $\langle V \rangle$ lies in the union of those associated primes. By Prime Avoidance, $\langle V \rangle$ lies in one of the associated primes. In section 2 of that paper, they are restricting to associated primes that don't contain $G_+$. If $G_1$ were contained in the union of the associated primes that don't contain $G_+$, then $G_+$ would be contained in a prime that doesn't contain $G_+$. So some element of $G_1$ is filter-regular.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thank you for the answer. But it is not clear to me that if we want to prove some result for general element then how can I consider a filter-regular element to prove the result. Like in Lemma 2.3, the result is for any general element. But in the proof f is filter-regular element.

Comment: Perhaps "general" is not clear? If $P$ is a property of points in a variety $V$, then "$P$ holds for general elements" if there exists a dense, open subset $U$ of the variety such that $P$ holds for every element of $U$. To prove that $P$ holds for general elements in $V$, it suffices to prove that it holds for general elements in a dense open subset $U$ (i.e., for all elements in some $U_1 \subset U$). The filter-regular elements of $G_1$ form an open set; I sketched a proof it is nonempty, thus dense. So it's sufficient to consider filter-regular elements.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @ZachTeitler In the same paper they have defined sequentially general elements "a_1,...,a_i of I is sequentially general  if for every j with j lies between 1 and i and every  fixed  a_1,...,a_{j-1} the element a_j is general in I ." (definition is given before Proposition 3.5). What is the relation between a_j being general in I and a_1,...a_{j-1}. What the definition actually mean?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps you should write an email to the authors of the paper.